# Building a basic SQL JOIN but need to also include a COUNT

Tags: sql

I have this simple JOIN query:

```
SELECT *
FROM content
JOIN statistics
ON content.content_id = statistics.content_id
WHERE statistics.content_id = '37' AND statistics.timestamp BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 00:00:00'
```

That JOIN works fine, and as there are 2 matching results in the STATISTICS table it gives me 2 identical rows back.

What I actually need to do though is count the results (using column user_ip as the unique value). Before I needed a join I was simply using this: `COUNT(DISTINCT(statistics.user_ip)) as hits`

How can I incorporate this into my new JOIN query to give me a single row back with a new column called 'hits' with 2 as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT content.content_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(statistics.user_ip)) as hits
FROM content
JOIN statistics
ON content.content_id = statistics.content_id
WHERE statistics.content_id = '37' AND statistics.timestamp BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 00:00:00'
group by content.content_id
```